# Tensorflow: index along specified dimension

Tags: tensorflow

The following code does unfortunately not work in Tensorflow:

```
id_translation = tf.argmax(z_pi_translation,1)
translations = z_mu_translation[:,id_translation,:]
```

So the id_translation op selects the index and this number should be used to index another tensor. I looked to tf.gather but not sure how to use it, this should be relative simple I think. Suggestions on how to do this indexing?

Edit:
I made a small code example that reproduces the issue:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

z_pi_translation = tf.random_normal([100,20])
z_mu_translation = tf.random_normal([100,20,3])

id_translation = tf.argmax(z_pi_translation,1)
translations = z_mu_translation[:,id_translation,:]

sess.run(translations)
```

Comment: Why doesn't this code work in tensorflow? I made a smaller example and it works. What error do you get?

Comment: Error is : ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 0
 From merging shape 1 with other shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tf.slice(z_mu_translation, tf.concat(0, [[0], id_translation], [0]), [-1, -1, -1])`